# Can you delete the backing document file behind a PDFView

Tags: swift, pdfview

In a PDFView (swift), once I set the document based on a local file URL is it OK for me to delete the PDF assuming it is view only?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
self.pdfView.document = .none         
self.pdfView.document = nil
```